# Toggling One Classes Opacity, on a Click of Another (button)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

On click of the hamburger menu, I already have an animation. What I want to do: is *upon* clicking the hamburger css/javascripted `<button>`. I want another class; my `.dropdownMenu` class to change it's `opacity` to `1`). Something like:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.hamburger', function () {
  $(this).toggleClass('.dropdownMenu'.style.opacity = 1);
});
```

```js
const hamburger = document.querySelector('.hamburger');

hamburger.addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.classList.toggle('is-active')
})
```

```css
body {
  background  : grey;
  }
.hamburger {
  display     : block;
  position    : relative;
  z-index     : 1;
  user-select : none;
  appearance  : none;
  border      : none;
  outline     : none;
  background  : none;
  cursor      : pointer;
  }
.hamburger span {
  display          : block;
  width            : 33px;
  height           : 4px;
  margin-bottom    : 5px;
  position         : relative;
  background-color : #eeeeee;
  border-radius    : 6px;
  z-index          : 1;
  transform-origin : 0 0;
  transition       : 0.4s;
  }
.hamburger:hover span:nth-child(2) {
  transform        : translateX(10px);
  background-color : #8c38ff;
  }
.hamburger.is-active span:nth-child(1) {
  transform        : translate(0px, -2px) rotate(45deg);
  background-color : #8c38ff;
  }
.hamburger.is-active span:nth-child(2) {
  opacity          : 0;
  transform        : translateX(15px);
  }
.hamburger.is-active span:nth-child(3) {
  transform        : translate(-3px, 3px) rotate(-45deg);
  background-color : #8c38ff;
  }
.hamburger.is-active:hover span {
  background-color : #8c38ff;
  }
.menu {
  display         : none;
  flex            : 1 1 0%;
  justify-content : center;
  margin          : 0 -16;
  letter-spacing  : 2px;
  }
.menu a {
  color           : ivory;
  margin          : 0 16;
  font-weight     : 600;
  text-decoration : none;
  transition      : 0.4s;
  padding         : 8px 16px;
  border-radius   : 99px;
  }
.menu a.is-active,
.menu a:hover {
  background-color : #8c38ff;
  }
.dropdown {
  position : relative;
  }
.dropdownMenu {
  position         : absolute;
  z-index          : 100;
  right            : -2rem;
  top              : calc(100% + 1.36rem);
  border-bottom    : 3px solid #8c38ff;
  border-left      : 3px solid #8c38ff;
  background-color : #212121;
  border-radius    : 0 0 15px 15px;
  padding          : 20px;
  padding-right    : 50px;
  opacity          : 0;
  }
.dropdownMenu a {
  color           : ivory;
  text-decoration : none;
  font-size       : 20px;
  opacity         : 1;
  }
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Company Name</h1>
    <div class="menu">
      <a href="#" class="is-active">Events</a>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Login</a>
      <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="hamburger">
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
      </button>
      <div class="dropdownMenu">
        <a href="#" class="link">Events</a>
        <a href="#" class="link">About</a>
        <a href="#" class="link">Login</a>
        <a href="#" class="is-active">Dashboard</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Generally it's not a good idea to set css properties with js. I would recommend using a class that has opacity = 1 for the needed element and toggle that.
As for changing that on click event, you should have no problem with js. 
Say this part, where you listen for clicks and toggle the class, add another toggle for the second element you wish to set opacity for. 

The jquery part you provided is not going to work: $(this).toggleClass('.dropdownMenu'.style.opacity = 1);
when you toggle class, it should not have the "." in it, and the style.opacity is not part of the class thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Method-1

This method adds and removes the `opacityStyle` class style from the `.dropdownMenu`.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.hamburger', function () {
  $('.dropdownMenu').toggleClass('opacityStyle')
});
```

```css
/* Added the following class style. */
.opacityStyle{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

---

##### Method-2

Clicking the `<button>` assigns the opacity of the `dropdownMenu` class style to `1` if `0`. Otherwise, clicking the `<button>` will assign the opacity of the `dropdownMenu` class style `1` to `0`.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.hamburger', function () {
  if($('.dropdownMenu').css("opacity") == "1")
    $('.dropdownMenu').css("opacity", "0");
  else
    $('.dropdownMenu').css("opacity", "1");
});
```

---

###### Code Snippet

```js
/* Made jQuery compatible for fewer lines of code. */
$('.hamburger').bind('click', function() {
  this.classList.toggle('is-active')
});

/* The following event handler method has been added. */
$(document).on('click', '.hamburger', function () {
  $('.dropdownMenu').toggleClass('opacityStyle')
});
```

```css
body {
  background  : grey;
}
.hamburger {
  display     : block;
  position    : relative;
  z-index     : 1;
  user-select : none;
  appearance  : none;
  border      : none;
  outline     : none;
  background  : none;
  cursor      : pointer;
}
.hamburger span {
  display          : block;
  width            : 33px;
  height           : 4px;
  margin-bottom    : 5px;
  position         : relative;
  background-color : #eeeeee;
  border-radius    : 6px;
  z-index          : 1;
  transform-origin : 0 0;
  transition       : 0.4s;
}
.hamburger:hover span:nth-child(2) {
  transform        : translateX(10px);
  background-color : #8c38ff;
}
.hamburger.is-active span:nth-child(1) {
  transform        : translate(0px, -2px) rotate(45deg);
  background-color : #8c38ff;
}
.hamburger.is-active span:nth-child(2) {
  opacity          : 0;
  transform        : translateX(15px);
}
.hamburger.is-active span:nth-child(3) {
  transform        : translate(-3px, 3px) rotate(-45deg);
  background-color : #8c38ff;
  }
.hamburger.is-active:hover span {
  background-color : #8c38ff;
}
.menu {
  display         : none;
  flex            : 1 1 0%;
  justify-content : center;
  margin          : 0 -16;
  letter-spacing  : 2px;
  }
.menu a {
  color           : ivory;
  margin          : 0 16;
  font-weight     : 600;
  text-decoration : none;
  transition      : 0.4s;
  padding         : 8px 16px;
  border-radius   : 99px;
}
.menu a.is-active,
.menu a:hover {
  background-color : #8c38ff;
}
.dropdown {
  position : relative;
}
.dropdownMenu {
  position         : absolute;
  z-index          : 100;
  right            : -2rem;
  top              : calc(100% + 1.36rem);
  border-bottom    : 3px solid #8c38ff;
  border-left      : 3px solid #8c38ff;
  background-color : #212121;
  border-radius    : 0 0 15px 15px;
  padding          : 20px;
  padding-right    : 50px;
  opacity          : 0;
}
.dropdownMenu a {
  color           : ivory;
  text-decoration : none;
  font-size       : 20px;
  opacity         : 1;
}

/* Added the following class style. */
.opacityStyle{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Company Name</h1>
    <div class="menu">
      <a href="#" class="is-active">Events</a>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Login</a>
      <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="hamburger">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </button>
      
      <div class="dropdownMenu">
        <a href="#" class="link">Events</a>
        <a href="#" class="link">About</a>
        <a href="#" class="link">Login</a>
        <a href="#" class="is-active">Dashboard</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```